# BigQuery to create features, is it suitable or will it run out of Memory?

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's imagine this scenario. I have a BitCoin transaction dataset ~ 1TB is size.

I would like to create features to train a machine learning application. For example, a simple feature can be:

```
WITH btc AS (SELECT * FROM bitcoin.transactions),
price_feature AS (SELECT datetime, AVG(price) from btc GROUP BY 1)
SELECT * FROM price_features
```

However, what if I have 100000s of such features? I know that for each new feature, I can run:

```
WITH btc AS (SELECT * FROM bitcoin.transactions),
some_feature AS ()
SELECT * FROM some_feature
```

But this will cost me 1TB=5$ * 100000, if I was to create 1 query per feature.

Is it possible to use BQ for something like:

```
WITH btc AS (SELECT * FROM bitcoin.transactions),
feature_1 AS (),
feature_2 AS (),
feature_... AS (),
feature_n AS ()

SELECT * FROM feature_1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM feature_2 
...
```

The problem is that even independent features sometimes take ~1-2 mins of BQ running time. Will I be able to put them all into 1 query? I feel like I have all sorts of memory problems etc. to face.

Comment: Well, BigQuery won't run out of memory, but it will be expensive! If you really are looking to create thousands of features (this seems like a lot of features where you'll surely have a lot of strong correlations?) I would approach it by scripting something outside of BigQuery, in Python for example, which can look through many queries and handle each sequentially.

Comment: @BenP Why would it be expensive in the last example? I'm running a single query, which does a single DB scan? It would only cost 5$ to analyse. Simple example: If I write 1 query per feature, and I have 2 features in total I pay 10$. However, if I simply use UNION the 2 features as in the last example, it costs 5$.

Comment: Yes I follow your logic, I guess it depends on how much data you'll be scanning to create thousands of features.

Comment: your question is more YES or NO question - which is not usually type of question for SO - in any case - I would say YES and just go ahead and try it - don't know what else to add here and obviously this is not something I would put as an answer :o)